# Manually running command in cmd produces different results than with Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

In Windows, I have a command `Bubbles.scr/s` that, when entered into the cmd terminal in any directory, starts the "Bubbles" screensaver with no issue. I'm trying to do this with Python via:

```
import os
os.system("Bubbles.scr/s")
```

But I receive the error

```
'Bubbles.scr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What's the issue here? Would it have something to with the fact that `Bubbles.scr` is located in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with path because when you open cmd ,the path where screen saver is present(i.e system32) is added in system variables so it executes perfectly but when you execute your python script, the path is set to current directory so it cant find Bubbbles.scr.your code is alright except for the path.the following code works:

```
import os
os.system("C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr /s")
```

Comment: So I've tried this before but went it doesn't work for me. I get the error ```'C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: can you add a screenshot ,what does it say because it worked for me.

Comment: I get the error message in my first comment. I think this has something to do with the ```SysWOW64``` directory but I'm at a loss.

Comment: What version of windows r you using and did your tried my code because its working for me and also which version of python are you using?

Comment: use the path, `where bubbles.scr` gives you.